# Create sparse matrix with diagonal blocks

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix A. How do I efficiently create a bigger sparse matrix that as A as diagonal blocks?

For example, for `n` = 2, I would have the matrix

```
A, 0*A
0*A, A
```

For example, lets say

```
from scipy.sparse import kron as spkron
from scipy.sparse import hstack, vstack
import numpy as np
A_dense = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
A = spkron(A_dense, 2)
n = 2
```

How I would do this very cumbersomely, would be to iteratively add all the elements, then stack up each row, and then stack up to the final matrix:

```
zeros = A * 0
rows = {}
for i in range(n):
    rows[i] = [zeros] * n
    rows[i][i] = A

rows_stack =  {}
for i in range(n):
    rows_stack[i] = hstack([r for r in rows[i]])
stacked = vstack([r for r in rows_stack.values()])
```

Comment: Both `spare.hstack` and `vstack` use `sparse.bmat` to create the matrix from blocks.  `bmat` in turn combined the `coo` attributes of the blocks to create a new `coo` matrix.  `block_diag` does the same thing, but streamlined a bit so you don't need to define the `0*A` block.  I know these things because I looked at the source code. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a dedicated function to create sparse diagonal block matrices in scipy. For your case, you have to create A and just pass it n times. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.block_diag.html

```py
from scipy.sparse import block_diag
block_diag((A, A))
```